# What is the meaning of Prabala Prarabdha Karma?

Tags: karma

What is Prabala Prarabdha karma? Please give examples of Prabala Prarabdha.

Comment: Prabal in Bengali means very powerful or intense. I think it means the same in Sanskrit too.